# Alignment of TOC with exotic numbering

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment

While answering this question : [French section numbering using bis, ter, etc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254149/french-section-numbering-using-bis-ter-etc/254255#254255), I realized that when you add (using `\addcontentsline`) some content to ToC with "non conventionnal numbering" (in my case 2 bis, 2 ter, etc), the title of the section is almost left-aligned with the usual section titles, but not exactly aligned.

For instance, the following MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{First section header}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Second section header}
\lipsum[2]
\section*{Third section header}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\numberline{2 bis} Bis section test}
\end{document}
```

produces [image]

I though this could be managed by redefining `\l@section`. Indeed, in the LaTeX Companion, it is mentioned that the third argument of `\@dottetocline` was the width of the box containing the section number. However, adding the following code to my preamble does not change anything.

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@section{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.5em}}
\makeatother
```

Any idea of why this happens, and what could be done to fix this ?

Comment: Thanks for following up on this.  It's nice to finally have the sectioning working the way I want it to!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When writing content to the ToC, you should be aware that macros could be expanded to reveal their inner workings. This expansion could lead to problems. Here's what happening in your instance, when looking at the `.toc` file:

```
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {0.1}First section header}{1}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {0.2}Second section header}{1}
\contentsline {section}{\hbox to\@tempdima {2 bis\hfil }Bis section test}{1}
```

Note how the manually-written `.toc` entry has `\hbox to\@tempdima{..}` rather than `\numberline`, even though you specified `\numberline`. As such, when the `.toc` file is read in for printing (with a call to `\tableofcontents`), `\@tempdima` may have a different meaning that what it should when the traditional `\numberline` is called.

One solution is provided through `\protect`ion from expansion:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
%\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{First section header}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Second section header}
\lipsum[2]
\section*{Third section header}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{2 bis}Bis section test}
\end{document}
```

The `.toc` file now resembles:

```
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {0.1}First section header}{1}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {0.2}Second section header}{1}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2 bis}Bis section test}{1}
```

For adjustment of the `\numberline` width in general, consider reading [Roman numerals become “too wide” in table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7415/5764).

Comment: Finally, the issue was the space left before `#1` in `\addcontentsline`. But I was unaware of the risks of expansion, thanks for your quick response.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use the `titlesec` package or use the `titlesec` package without the `explicit` option your redefinition of `\l@section` works fine.