# French bis/ter/quater/quinquies section numbering with manual line breaks

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, numbering, line-breaking

As a follow-up to my previous Question [French section numbering using bis, ter, etc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254149/french-section-numbering-using-bis-ter-etc), I'm attempting to manually add line breaks in my section titles that show up in the body of the text as intended but do not break manually in the Table of Contents.  I hope this is clear - if not, the screencap below should hopefully show what I'm after:

[image: Breaks in Section but not TOC]

This I achieved using manual section numbering, which is what I sought to avoid in the first Question.  The syntax for that is as follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titletoc}


\titleformat{\section}[block]{\normalfont\normalsize\itshape\filcenter}{\thesection. ---}{0.5em}{}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{First section header}
\lipsum[1]
\section*{1 \textit{bis}. --- Second section header is very long \\ and I want to control the location where it breaks}\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{1 \textit{bis}    Second section header is very long and I want to control the location where it breaks}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

Here's my non-working MWE, based on the syntax [mvienney](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/78545/mvienney) came up with in the aforementioned Question.  Note that I *did not* use this syntax to come up with the image above.  If I try to put line breaks in the section titles for this syntax, it fails to compile.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titletoc}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \bislist
\seq_set_split:Nnn \bislist {;} {bis;ter;quater;quinquies;sexies;septies;octies;novies;decies}
\NewDocumentCommand {\bisprint} {m}
 {
  \seq_item:Nn \bislist {#1}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcounter{bis}
\stepcounter{bis}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\normalfont\normalsize\itshape\filcenter}{\thesection. --- #1}{0.5em}{}[\setcounter{bis}{1}]
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}[block]{\normalfont\normalsize\itshape\filcenter}{\arabic{section} \textit{\bisprint{\arabic{bis}}}. --- #1}{0.5em}{}[ \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\numberline{\arabic{section} \textit{\bisprint{\arabic{bis}}}}#1} \stepcounter{bis}]

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@section{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{3.5em}} %change the last parameter to 2.5em if you do not go further that ter and to 3.5 if you don't go further than quater
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{First section header}
\lipsum[1]
\section*{Second section header is very long and I want to control the location where it breaks}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one option: Using a special (robust) macro `\bodyonlynewline` as your manual line-breaking technique. This macro will only break the line inside the body text, but not the ToC.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \bislist
\seq_set_split:Nnn \bislist {;} {bis;ter;quater;quinquies;sexies;septies;octies;novies;decies}
\NewDocumentCommand {\bisprint} {m}
 {
  \seq_item:Nn \bislist {#1}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcounter{bis}
\stepcounter{bis}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\normalfont\normalsize\itshape\filcenter}{\thesection. --- #1}{0.5em}{}[\setcounter{bis}{1}]
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}[block]{\normalfont\normalsize\itshape\filcenter}{\arabic{section} \textit{\bisprint{\arabic{bis}}}. --- #1}{0.5em}{}[ \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\arabic{section} \textit{\bisprint{\arabic{bis}}}}#1} \stepcounter{bis}]

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@section{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{3.5em}} %change the last parameter to 2.5em if you do not go further that ter and to 3.5 if you don't go further than quater
\makeatother
\DeclareRobustCommand{\bodyonlynewline}{}% Macro does nothing
\let\oldtableofcontents\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
  \oldtableofcontents
  \DeclareRobustCommand{\bodyonlynewline}{\\}% Macro breaks line only _after_ ToC
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{First section header}
\lipsum[1]
\section*{Second section header is very long \bodyonlynewline and I want to control the location where it breaks}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

Note the use of `\protect\numberline` in the `numberless` formatting of `\section`. Otherwise [expansion of `\numberline` could cause problems](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/255507/5764).

Comment: I'm using package     tocloft, which appears to conflict with this syntax.  Any idea for a workaround?

Comment: Your syntax works when I disable tocloft, but since I'll want to reformat the TOC, I'd like to keep that package in.  I edited the Question to include that package in the preamble for clarity.

Comment: @grfrazee: You're dealing with ToC-related content. Why would you not mention that you're using [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) from the start?! Also, I think it's better to use [`titletoc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) since you're using [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec).

Comment: Apologies, I'm new to TeX and haven't figured out all the interrelationships between things yet.

Comment: I've changed to using [titletoc](http://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) in lieu of [tocloft](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) per your suggestion, and am marking the Question as answered.  Thanks for the help.