# Cross-referencing Sections with French Latin Section Numbering

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing, french

This question is tied to my other question about [French section numbering using bis, ter, etc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254149/french-section-numbering-using-bis-ter-etc).  The previous question gave me a method to number the different sections with the latin *bis*, *ter*, and others in sequential order.

Now I am trying to cross-reference these sections but the cross reference numbering is not working out correctly.  Please consider the MWE below, which is slightly tweaked from the answer to the aforementioned question.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{totcount}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \bislist
\seq_set_split:Nnn \bislist {;} {bis;ter;quater;quinquies;sexies;septies;octies;novies;decies}

\NewDocumentCommand {\bisprint} {m}
 {
  \seq_item:Nn \bislist {#1}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newtotcounter{bismax}
\newcounter{bis}
\stepcounter{bis}
\setcounter{bismax}{1}

\newcommand{\bisadd}{\stepcounter{bis} \setcounter{bismax}{\minof{4}{\maxof{\thebismax}{\thebis-1}}}}

\AtBeginDocument{\newlength{\bislength}
\settowidth{\bislength}{\textit{\bisprint{\totvalue{bismax}}}}
\addtolength{\bislength}{1.5em}}

\titleformat{\section}[block]{\normalfont\large\normalfont\filcenter}{\thesection. --- #1}{0.5em}{}[\setcounter{bis}{1}]

\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}

\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}[block]{\normalfont\large\normalfont\filcenter}{\arabic{section} \textit{\bisprint{\arabic{bis}}}. --- #1}{0.5em}{}[ \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\arabic{section} \textit{\bisprint{\arabic{bis}}}}#1} \bisadd{}]

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@section{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{\bislength}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}



\tableofcontents

\section{First section header}\label{Sec1}
\lipsum[5]
\section*{Second section header}\label{Sec1bis}
\lipsum[6]
\section*{Third section header}\label{Sec1ter}
\lipsum[7]
Let's reference Section \ref{Sec1bis} and \ref{Sec1ter} here.  This should have said "Section 1 \textit{bis} and Section 1 \textit{ter}."  You will see that the cross-references do not work out correctly.

\end{document}
```

This produces the following output:

[image: No. 1]
[image: No. 2]

As you can see, the last paragraph attempts to cross-reference Sections 1 *bis* and 1 *ter*, but the Latin ordinals aren't properly shown.  I assume this has something to do with the `\section*` command, but I really don't know for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an idea with minimal impact on the usual commands: with `\section+` you introduce a “bis” section. When a `\section` without suffix is scanned, the normal counter is stepped and the `bis` counter is reset.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\section}[block]
  {\normalfont\large\normalfont\filcenter}
  {\thesection. --- }
  {0em}
  {}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \origsection \section

\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{s t+ o m }
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   { \origsection* { #4 } }
   {
    \stepcounter{Hsection}
    \IfBooleanTF{#2}
     {
      \addtocounter{section}{-1}
      \stepcounter{bis}
     }
     {
      \setcounter{bis}{1}
     }
    \IfNoValueTF{#3}
     { \origsection { #4 } }
     { \origsection [ #3 ] { #4 } }
   }
 }

\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand {\bisprint} {}
 {
  \int_case:nnF { \value{bis} }
   {
    {0}{}
    {1}{}
    {2}{~bis}
    {3}{~ter}
    {4}{~quater}
    {5}{~quinquies}
    {6}{~sexies}
    {7}{~septies}
    {8}{~octies}
    {9}{~novies}
    {10}{~decies}
   }
   { ~ HEY! }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}\textit{\bisprint}}
\newcounter{bis}
\newcounter{Hsection}


\begin{document}



\tableofcontents

\section{First section header}\label{Sec1}
\lipsum[5]
\section+{Second section header}\label{Sec1bis}
\lipsum[6]
\section+{Third section header}\label{Sec1ter}
\lipsum[7]

Let's reference Section \ref{Sec1bis} and \ref{Sec1ter} here.  This should have said "Section 1 
\textit{bis} and Section 1 \textit{ter}."  You will see that the cross-references do not work out 
correctly.

\section{This should be 2}

\section+{This should be 2bis}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I leave to you further refinements.

Comment: I have other syntax that requires `\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}` to work.  Putting the `[explicit]` flag in makes the section headers in the body of the document disappear with your syntax.  How can I avoid this?

Comment: @grfrazee My experience is that the `explicit` option is almost never needed. If you *must* use it, put `#1` in the now empty pair of braces at the end of the `\titleformat` command.

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks.  I especially like that this solution doesn't redefine the `\section*{}` command, which was something that didn't quite sit well with me on my MWE.

Answer (score 2):

You can change your `numberless` `\titleformat` to the following:

```
\makeatletter
\providecommand{\phantomsection}{}% To work with hyperref, if needed
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}[block]
  {\normalfont\large\normalfont\filcenter}
  {\phantomsection% Set hyperref mark
   \protected@xdef\@currentlabel{\thesection~\textit{\bisprint{\arabic{bis}}}}%
   \arabic{section} \textit{\bisprint{\arabic{bis}}}. --- #1}
  {0.5em}
  {}
  [ \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\arabic{section} \textit{\bisprint{\arabic{bis}}}}#1} \bisadd{}]
\makeatother
```

This updates `\@currentlabel` - used by the `\label`-`\ref` system to include your `\bisprint`-ed number.

[image]

The above also works as expected when [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) is used.

Comment: I believe that all that's still needed to do in order to make this code work with `hyperref` is to change the two instances of `\stepcounter` to `\refstepcounter`.

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to add `hyperref` to my MWE.  What would have to be done to get this to work with `hyperref`?

Comment: @Mico, thanks, I was typing my comment when you posted yours.  I'll give that a try.

Comment: @grfrazee: See the minor update to the answer, which adds `\phantomsection` where needed.